# trapz function giving strange results

Tags: matlab

I'm using the trapz function on two sets of data and there's something wrong.

Here is a view of the data:
[image: pressure drag coefficient and lift coefficient]

So you can understand my problem; y-axis is pressure coefficient Cp, x-axis is angle (49 values in total, 0:7.5:360), data with the green square matrix is the data obtained from the experiment, the red curve is basically Cp*sin(angle) while the pink one is Cp*cos(angle)

Using trapz on the red one works perfectly, it gives 7.5, and if I reverse the input arguments for trapz I get the negative of this number! The problem is with the pink graph, using trapz gives a huge number (it's wrong, I shouldn't be getting this) and when switching the input arguments I get another huge number, not the negative of the first number, that is weird, I don't know what is wrong, so I used quad (needs a function) to test the results of trapz

```
for i = 1:48
    y = @(x) (Cp(i+1) - Cp(i)) / ( theta_rad(i+1) - theta_rad(i) ) * x .* sin(x);
    clll(i) = -0.5* quad(y,theta_rad(i), theta_rad(i+1));

end
clll = sum(clll);

for j = 1:48
    f = @(t) (Cp(j+1) - Cp(j)) / ( theta_rad(j+1) - theta_rad(j) ) * t .* cos(t);
    cdddp(i) = 0.5* quad(f,theta_rad(j), theta_rad(j+1));

end

cdddp = sum(cdddp);
```

For the first loop (quad of the red curve) I got a very close answer, the error was probably due to the linear interpolation I used between points and for the second loop I got a sensible answer, a very small number which is in the range of the answer I'm looking for. I also tried trapezoidal rule in Excel and I got this huge number again, so it's something I'm doing wrong.

---

**Edit:**

I just found a mistake, I was using the trapezoidal using angles in degrees rather than radians! Now I'm getting much smaller numbers but I think there's another mistake because the integral using quad gives a more sensible answer.

Here's the code I'm using for trapz

```
Cdp = 0.5*trapz( theta*pi/180, Cp.*cosd(theta) ); %pressure drag coefficient

Cl = -0.5*trapz(theta*pi/180, Cp.*sind(theta) ); %lift coefficient
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working now, after using **radians** in the trapz function I got the correct answer. The interpolation I was trying to do is nonsense! I managed to create a fit using Curve Fitting Tool, it's very efficient

This

```
Cdp = 0.5*trapz( theta*pi/180, Cp.*cosd(theta) ); %pressure drag coefficient
```

can be achieved using the tool by:

```
fit1 = createFit( theta*pi/180, Cp.*cosd(theta) ); 
##createFit is generated by MatLab and I only need parts of it, all the plots commands were removed.
Cdp = 0.5*integrate(fit1,0,2*pi) ##"integrate" < this is why the tool is great, No need to export the coefficients to the workspace, create a function handle then use quad
```